# Email sending is failed in Opencart using Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, opencart2.x

**Email sending is failed in Opencart.**

While `Add Order History` by admin, have to send the order status to customer. When I click the `Add History` button, the following error is alert.

> Error.Password not accepted from server!

[image]

My Mail settings is:

[image]

In all cases the mail is not sending for me.

Please help me ...How can I make this working..
My **opencart version** is  **2.0.3.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

Allowing less secure apps to access your account will solve the problem.

Login to your account, then at the link

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and choose **Turn on**.

Comment: This worked for me. I set up a site for a client and gmail accounts weren't receiving emails. Admin and customer emails were both failing and are now working fine, at least for the time being.